# JAXB ignoring xml tag attribute

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, moxy

I read xml files with JAXB. I have the following structure

```
<A>
  <B value="some string" />
</A>
```

I have the following model

```
@XmlRootElement
class A{
  @XmlElement(name = "B", required = true)
  @XmlPath("B/@value")
  String b;
}
```

I read the B tags value attribute in my b Instance variable.

But in some XML files i have in the B tag following Structure `<#B/>`
While JAXB unmarshall the files i become exception that the format is not correct.
 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[19,4]

Comment: I am also trying something similar but seems like `@XmlPath` does not have any impact on my `JaxB Marshalling`. The created XML output with or without `@XmlPath` is the same. I tried to search a lot but seems like nothing is working for me. I have even added the `jaxb.properties` file added to my package. Did it work finally for you? if so then how did you resolve the same?

Answer (score 1):

You should just have the following without the `@XmlElement` annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement
class A{
  @XmlPath("B/@value")
  String b;
}
```

Comment: This is not working. I have a tag <#B> but the normal Normal is <B value="1323" />. If the Parser see the tag <#B/> he throws an exception

Comment: @SadikHasan - What exception do you get?

Comment: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20140107-a992a67): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[19,4] . I catch the exception and i can see it is at the place where the parse see the tag <#B>.

Comment: @SadikHasan - `<#B>` isn't a valid element name.  The error is coming from the underlying parser.  You will need to clean in the XML before trying to unmarshal it.